# Why is the Lenovo Thinkpad X301 not Ubuntu Certified?

Tags: lenovo, thinkpad

The Lenovo Thinkpads X100e, X201 and X220i are Ubuntu Certified.

Why is the X301 not Certified? Never been tested for certification or failed the certification for some (which) reasons?

Answer (score 5):

Possible reason: [suspend/resume does not work out of the box](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/11.10/LENOVO/ThinkPad%20X301/I:BzWTop:Co4:I8g:CLo:B9ip:EZZ:I8g:BMb:I8g/status/). Otherwise it could indeed never been tested and you will have to wait for them to test it.

---

So let not everyone face the same problem as you have: why wait for Lenovo and Conanical if we can do it ourself! See https://friendly.ubuntu.com where we can add our own experience.

> Ubuntu Friendly is an open hardware validation programme for desktops, netbooks and laptops which allows you to validate your computer as "Ubuntu Friendly" based test results. The Ubuntu Friendly website lists systems that are were tested and work to different degrees with a particular release of Ubuntu.
>
> Ubuntu Friendly is a community driven hardware validation programme, not a certification programme (for the Certification see Ubuntu Certified programme). Its goal is to have a list of rated systems that people have tested with a particular release of Ubuntu.

There is only 1 report for this system (and it is against 11.10). Maybe **you** (yes anyone on AU) can add yourself with your experience? [It should only takes 15 minutes](https://friendly.ubuntu.com/participate/) and you would be helping others with the same machine. And that does not apply for just your machine but any one reading this ;)

Comment: _Ubuntu Friendly_ has [been sunset](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuFriendly)